# for loop debug in java - value overflow

Tags: java, debugging, for-loop

I'm working out this problem from Programming in Java book-site (for practice, not a HW.. Q15 in http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/13flow/) :

Find the sum for the harmonic series 1/1 + 1/4 + 1/9 + 1/16 + ... + 1/N2 . 
There are 4 variants of for loops, some of them are supposed to give the right answer. My expected answers are in comments, and the actual results are below.

```
public class OneThreeExFifteen {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int N = 1000000;
        double s1=0 , s2 = 0, s3 = 0, s4=0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= N ; i++ )
            s1 = s1 + 1 / ( i * i );        // Expected  s1 = 1 
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= N ; i++ ) 
            s2 = s2 + 1.0 / i * i;          // Expected  s2 = 1000000 
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= N ; i++) 
            s3 = s3 + 1.0 / (i * i) ;       // Correctly computes the series sum 
        for (int i = 1; i <= N ; i++ ) 
            s4 = s4 + 1 / (1.0 * i * i) ;   // Correctly computes the serires sum

        System.out.println("for loop 1" + s1);
        System.out.println("for loop 2" +s2);
        System.out.println("for loop 3" +s3);
        System.out.println("for loop 4" +s4);


    }
}
```

RESULT:

```
for loop 1       (  I get a Divide by 0  error - had to comment out this loop) 
for loop 2   1000000.0 
for loop 3   Infinity 
for loop 4   1.64493306684877
```

QUESTION - 
Why do I get

a) Divide by zero error?

b) Infinity result in case of for loop 3  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, as another has already stated, you have performed integer division with the code `1 / ( i * i )` in multiple places.  In Java, an `int` divided by an `int` must remain an `int`, so `1` divided by a larger number yields `0`.  But you aren't dividing by zero for that reason.  That just makes you *add* zero, perfectly un-exceptional.

You are looping for `i` from `0` to `1000000` (1 million).  Before you get too far, `i` is `65536` (`2` to the 16th power).  When this iteration occurs, **`i * i` overflows** (the "real" result is `2^32`) and you get `0`.  This result is causing divide by zero in the first loop.

Demonstration program:

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
{
  int i = 1 << 16;  // 2^16, or 65536
  System.out.println(i);
  int j = i * i;
  System.out.println(j);
}
```

Output:

```
65536
0
```

The 3rd `for` loop is very similar, except that floating point division yields `Infinity` (a legal floating point value) instead of a divide by zero error.

The second and fourth `for` loops correctly promote the multiplication to `double` before the operation, so no overflow occurs.  But the second `for` loop is missing its parentheses, so `1` is added each time.  The fourth `for` loop correctly computes the sum.

Comment: Knowing the math that (2^16)^2 = 2^32 = 0 helps I guess. But computers are strong enough that I just did `for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000000 ; i++)if(i*i==0)System.out.println(i);` :)

Answer (score 3):

You're suffering from integer division here:

```
s1 = s1 + 1 / ( i * i );
```

`i` is an `int`, and every number without a suffix is implicitly `int`, so you're dividing 1/1, which results in 1, luckily.

Things happen when `i` increases though - if it's greater than 1, you're going to get 0 for every result until the end of the loop.

Something unusual happens in my debugger when figuring this out - the division by zero occurs when the number is `65536` - you're getting an overflow on 65536<sup>2</sup> - which is 2<sup>32</sup> - which results in the int value becoming 0.

The second loop:

```
s2 = s2 + 1.0 / i * i;
```

You're getting burned by operator precedence.  Division and multiplication have higher precedence than addition, so what this is actually doing is:

```
s2 = s2 + ((1.0 / i) * i);
```

You divide correctly, but your operator precedence is all wrong.

The third loop:

```
s3 = s3 + 1.0 / (i * i) ;
```

This is the same issue as above, but since you're in a floating-point context, [anything divided by 0 results in a signed `Infinity`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2)

Comment: Exactly cruncher. I know the first loop wont give me right answer, but it shouldnt see a divide by 0 error right

Comment: @Nik no you absolutely should. With a 32-bit signed integer 65536*65536 = 0

Answer (score 3):

`System.out.println(65536*65536);`

This will output 0.

I think this explains your problem for division by 0. You're getting an [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). The integer can only hold numbers up to a certain point.

However as stated elsewhere integer division is hurting you a lot. Even if you didn't get division by 0, your answers would be wrong because of integer division.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is just an overflow bug.
One simple way to prove this is displaying the value of i before dividing (it would be 65536, or 2^16).
The limit for an int is 2^32 and integers loops around when they go past their max value, so 2^32 = 0

(i * i) = (2^16 * 2^16) = 2^32 = 0